# How can we attribute Google Ad campaign to an app user in Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, google-ads-api, firebase-analytics

We are using Google Ads as a source for new users of our app. We have it linked to Firebase and can see the install (first_open) events in Google Ad words.

We would like to record the Google Ad campaign information against our authenticated Firebase users in our back-end database so we can better track value of campaigns over time.

Is there some way to hook into the Firebase SDK in the Flutter app to listen for/retrieve this information as it is sent to Google Ads when the app is first installed? Or is there another way we can use for source attribution tracking across both iOS and Android installs?

Thanks!